# Regex in bash: word class not generating a match

Tags: regex, bash

I have been agonizing over this for hours. Why is this happening?

```
$ if [[ "test" =~ \w+ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
no

$ if [[ "t" =~ \w+ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
no

$ if [[ "w" =~ \w+ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
yes

$ if [[ "wwwww" =~ \w+ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
yes
```

It's as if the escaping backslash is doing nothing. Why is that so? I noticed wrapping the regex in quotes doesn't help:

```
$ if [[ "test" =~ "\w+" ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
no
```

If it matters, this line is in a bash function, sourced from an `.sh` file and run on zsh.

Comment: The `\w` character class doesn't exist in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash represents its character classes a little different (from what you're expecting). Documentation available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html). The following should work:

```
if [[ "test" =~ '^[[:alnum:]]+$' ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

Comment: Perfect -- thanks. I'm surprised I was unable to find this out on the interwebs.

Comment: `$ if [[ "t!(\2g/*2" =~ [[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`
`yes`

The `[[:alnum:]]` seems to be too generous.

Comment: Use `'^[[:alnum:]]+$'` if you want the entire string to be alphanumeric - the current version only checks if 1 or more `[:alnum:]` exists in the string.